# Does replacement hold for $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to decide which ZFC axioms hold for $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal. I dont think replacement holds, and for that I'm considering the following function: $f(x)=|\mathscr{P}(x)|$, that is a set mapping to the cardinality of its power set. This way $f(\omega)=\omega_1$ which is not a member of $\omega_1$. Is this correct?

Also, I cannot decide for axiom of choice, does it hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler counterexample to show that the Axiom schema of replacement fails for infinitely many formulas $\varphi$. I will use the (somewhat unrigorous) definition of replacement: For any definable function $f$, the image of a set under $f$ is always a set.

For $\alpha > 0$, let $f_\alpha$ denote the constant map that maps all elements to $\alpha$. This is clearly a definable mapping. However, the image is always $\{\alpha\}$, which is not an element of $\omega_1$ (as it is not an ordinal).

Answer (score 3):

This is a question from my still-running (until Sunday night, 2023-01-22 23:59) set theory open book exam, so I won't give any concrete answer.

But for the Axiom of Choice part, let me say that it's heavily dependent on your formalisation of "The Axiom of Choice".  There are a lot of different statements equivalent to the Axiom of Choice when you have ZF set theory in the background, that fail to be equivalent to AC if you don't have full ZF.  Because $\omega_1$ is such a "weird" structure if you're thinking in terms of models of set theory, and in particular because it fails other fairly basic axioms from ZF, what might seem like a fairly innocuous equivalence of statements may no longer hold in that setting.  You really have to go to the formula you're considering to be your gold-standard definition of AC, and take it apart one quantifier at a time to assess whether it holds for the structure in question.